# Create Docker Image From Github and Publish to Hub

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

My github repository link is https://github.com/ferdasonmez/oyente. I forked a github site and made sme changes on some lib versions. Now I want to push it to Docker. I already created a repository under my docker account. ferdaozdemir/oyente

Using the below yml file, I am trying to create the image but nothing happens. I already created the secrets for Docker under Github settings. This can easily be recreated by forking the repository and entering your own secrets.

```yaml
name: Build Docker Container Image
on: push
jobs:
  build-container:
    name: Build container
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Push to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER_NAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          repository: ferdaozdemir/oyente
          tags: latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing steps. I have some repos with a similar setup (*i.e.* `Dockerfile` in the top-level directory) but I also run steps to

- checkout
- build (where I now use buildx)
- log into the Docker Hub
- build and push
- and also report and commit a timestamp (to force cache changes)

I include one of these below (source is [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/drd/blob/master/.github/workflows/docker.yaml). It may not be the most minimal setup but it had been working for me quite reliably, including via scheduled (*i.e* `cron`) actions.  I am skipping the last two items here (see [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/drd/blob/master/.github/workflows/docker.yaml) for the complete file):

```
name: docker
on:
  push:
  schedule:
  - cron: "22 2 * * 1"
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    #- name: Set up QEMU
    #  uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

    - name: Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

    - name: Login
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        
    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        push: true
        tags: rocker/drd:latest
```

Comment: I updated the workflow file

Comment: Great.  Feel free to upvoate (click on upward-triangle) or accept (click on tickmark you are OP see) if you found the answer helpful as that is how SO tends to spread the karma around.

Comment: Now, I get this Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to parse stage name "CLI": invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: All I can assure you (and the public logs of the actions at my repo will show too) is that it works for me as posted.  If your `Dockerfile` differs that you need to work out why and how.  Hint: `context: .` already specifies the top-level `Dockerfile`. Login already happened.  I do not use `repository` but `tags` to denote the target repo and `tags` should be `owner/repository:tag`.